# Delete Facebook Session After Login with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the facebook php sdk for a one-click login and registration. After a user is authenticated I am adding the user to my own db and session and then I want to immediately delete the facebook session.

I cant find any documentation on how to delete the facebook session without deleting my own session.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_code'])) {
    unset ($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_code']);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_access_token'])) {
    unset ($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_access_token']);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_user_id'])) {
    unset ($_SESSION['fb_' . FB_APP_ID . '_user_id']);
}
```

Not sure if there is already a method in the sdk that does this for you?