# facebook how to delete cookie on logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the JS and PHP SDK and I can login a user successfully using facebook. 
However logout doesnt seem to work (I can log a user out of my site but not out from facebook ).

Here is my logout code :

```
require_once('../libs/facebook/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook( array (
    'appId'  => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx',
    'cookie' => true
    )
    );

    $fb_key = 'fbsr_'.$facebookConfig['app_id'];

 // set_cookie($fb_key, '', '', '', '/', '');
  //$facebook->setSession(NULL);

$facebook->destroySession();
$facebook->getLogoutUrl();

$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$files = array();
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $files[] = $key;
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);

}
```

I have tried to use the following below to delete the cookie but I got an error message that setcookie is not a function

```
$fb_key = 'fbsr_'.$facebookConfig['app_id'];
setcookie($fb_key, '', time()-3600);
$facebook->destroySession();
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't post a comment on your question, so here's an 'answer'.

Have you looked at this SO post? 
[Delete Facebook Session After Login with PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842301/delete-facebook-session-after-login-with-php-sdk)

More people are struggling on this, from what I've read. And nobody seems to know if there's a native function within the SDK. So unsetting it manually might be your best bet.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I didn't manage to logout using this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a **user access token** to the logout url.

Example from my app.

```
 if($_GET['destroy']){
   $facebook->destroySession(); 
 }
$params = array( 'next' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed/?ref=logout&destroy=true', 'access_token' => $access_token);
$logout=$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
```